# Reverse Bivariate Interpolation

Tags: math

I am given a table, indexed on 2 dimensions (x,y), with values(not necessarily ordered, though I think it isn't a horrendously unsafe assumption) z given, such that f(x, y) = z

So given an x and y, I interpolate to find a z value. Now given an x value(or y I suppose, not really important) and a z value, I need to find that y value that corresponds to the data. Is it possible to do this without the knowledge of an ordering in the z values of the table? If there is an ordering to the z values of the table is it possible? In my head, given ordering, it should be possible to find a unique solution, but I don't know how I can do it if I am not given ordering.

Comment: can you make any assumptions on the f function, such as : is it continuous ? smooth ? linear in x or y ? How do you interpolate z when given x and y ?

Comment: Bivariate linear interpolation when given x or y, so I am assuming linearity and continuity, by construction. I _believe_ I can assume it is smooth, though I'm not quite certain how that helps.      
  
I kinda worked the problem a bit in my head, and I think the only way to sufficiently do it is to assume it is ordered(strictly increasing or decreasing) or you may come across the problem of multiple solutions. I then came to think that since it is data values and I am not necessarily looking for a _specific_ answer, just one that works, it is okay to do a reverse interpolation.

Comment: If the function is either constant or has local minima/maxima (i.e. it's not monotonic increasing/decreasing) for a particular constant `x`, there may be multiple `y` values where `z` has that specific value, so a unique solution may not be possible. If you know a specific range of `y` values where your desired solution should fall, and the function is "smooth enough" in that neighborhood, you may be able to find one, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some or preferably all of the data? Assuming it is linear and continuous, we have n copies of ax +by = z. Let's say x=3 and z=4, we have 3 unknowns which we can put in a matrix with n rows and 3 columns. The first row would look like `3 b 4` since we are treating a, y and z as unknowns. Now try echelon row reduction. More specifically, do row1 - row2 (now don't do row2 - row1), row1-row3, row1-row4... row2-row3, row2-row4... there should be nchoose2 of these permutations. If there is a solution then each permutation will be in the form `qia=qjz` (the a and z won't be there of course) where qi and qj are the known numbers and q,i and j are constant.

Comment: Can't post the data, but I didn't consider using a row reduction technique, which may have worked. If you look at my comment above though you'll see I recognized that multiple solutions were not a problem(in my use case) and a linear search on the data will be able to determine whether or not a solution exists at all.